# Regular expression to Find the text between two tabs (java pattens)

Tags: java, regex

I have a text like this

```
500     Robin Stuart    zzzzzzz
```

I want to get the text Robin STuart which is enclossed within two tabs.
Can someone help me with a regular expression for this.
I came up with `(^.*?)(\t)(^.*?)(\t)` but its not compiling.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html \t should be Ok. Are you using Pattern class or what are you using?

Comment: `String.split()` is your friend.

Comment: Yes Java pattern class.How am i supposed to get only The text between the two tabs to a String value.

Comment: +1 for `String.split`

Comment: If the String is delimited consistently with `\\t` you might as well use `split('\t')[1]` like @BrianRoach suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unnecessarily  using `^` second time in `(^.*?)(\t)(^.*?)(\t)` - probably copy-paste mistake. Use:

```
String s = "500 Robin Stuart    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\t)(.*?)(\t)");
Matcher m1 = p.matcher(s);
if (m1.find()){
    System.out.println(m1.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String s = "500\tRobin Stuart\tzzzzzzz";
    s = s.replaceAll(".*\t(.+)\t.*", "$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```